# Print to locate the error code block

Tags: c++, rstudio, rcpp

Hi great C++ programmers,

I've been in this situation many times, but I still don't know how to solve it.

I am programming in C++ in Rstudio, and my program runs into a fatal error which needs me to restart. I want to locate where the mistake is in my code. What I often do is adding some detection lines like:

```
int main()
{
    ...code block;

    std::cout<<"1.1\n";

    ...code block;

    std::cout<<"1.2\n";

    ...code block;

    std::cout<<"1.3\n";

    ...code block;

    std::cout<<"1.4\n";

    return 1;
}
```

Then I run the code.

The weird thing is, before it runs into "fatal error", sometimes I got "1.1" printed on the console, sometimes I got "1.1" and "1.2", sometimes I got "1.1", "1.2" and "1.3, and sometimes I got nothing.

I guess it has something to do with the operating system because it is the operating system that got the order to print something which would take some time, but meanwhile the CPU was executing forward the code and met the fatal error.

Or, maybe it's the way the codes were compiled that results in such thing?

Is there anyway to solve it? I just want the program to print out everything I asked before it runs into "fatal error".

Thanks!

The compiler optimization could reorder the code, making the printouts unreliable. You are coding C++ in the R environment, and the default g++ compiler optimization is set to -O2. Go to your R directory, search for a file named "Makeconf". Open it with a text editor, locate command "CXX11FLAGS = -O2 ...", erase "-O2", save the file and rebuild your program. Other commands like "CXXFLAGS = -O2 ..." may also need to be modified. Code will run in strictly sequential order by then.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded, this sounds like either a race-condition or a memory error. What is the fatal error?

Comment: It is not multi-threaded, and based on my past experience, such fatal error is often caused by array/vector overflow...@Ben

Comment: While logging, use `std::cout << message << std::endl` (to get the information out as soon as possible)

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to use a debugger.  If you don't know how to use the debugger, take time now to learn.

Comment: Found solution long time ago, just passing by and speak to self: those weird things happening in debugging, e.g. unable to print the supposed, periodically failing to print at the same position in code in multiple runs, periodically failing to return function values in multiple runs, are all "undefined behavior"--google it, 99.99% caused by index being out of bound somewhere somehow. Never think your algorithm is too good to get an out-of-bound. To guarantee printout before buggy code block, use longjmp in <setjmp.h>. Jump to main function and exit after every cout<<.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `std::cout` which is **not** what R uses, and you get caught up in two different buffering schemes.

Easy solution:  use `Rcpp::Rcout` instead which redirects into R's output stream.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I tried your solution many times but it seems it won't help. But I've found a remote way to locate the error: use a std::ofstream variable. Instead of outputting to the console, write a file with the name "file 1.1.txt" to a specific folder. In this way there won't be any uncertainty. Based on this fact, do you have any better ideas? This method is effective but troublesome.. I still want the results projected directly onto the console..

Comment: I overlooked that you start with `int main()` -- if so then this has nothing to do with R, Rcpp or RStudio.